# Get value of selected drop down list item

Tags: javascript, onchange, html-select

Good Evening, i have these dynamically generated dropdown list in my JSP:`

```
    <td><select name="model" id="model"  onchange="convertDropDownToTextBox()">

                            <c:forEach items="${model_list}" var="item">

                                <option value="${item.modelId}">${item.modelName}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                                                            <option value="100">Add New Model</option>

            </select></td>
```

and i tried these script to get the selected value from these dropdown :

```
function convertDropDownToTextBox(){
    var select = document.getElementById("model");
    var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedString);
}
```

the problem here is that it always gives 1 for every item selected in the dropdown however i f i changed the onChange to be `onchange="alert(this.value)"` it prints the right values!! how that come? and how to get the actual index of every item selected in the DropDown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the problem is but this works for me:

```
var select = document.getElementById("model");
select.onchange = function(){
    var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedString);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/PS4zy/1/

Comment: where's the action on the select element in the HTML?

Comment: The 'onchange' event is declared in the javascript, that way you son't need to put any javascript in your HTML. Take a look at the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `event` object into the Endpoint function:

```
<select onchange="convertDropDownToTextBox(event)">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

And then you can access the value `event.target.value` from within the function:

```
function convertDropDownToTextBox(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```