# How to calculate the price according to the quantity selection in dropdown in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm doing a shopping cart like application In my dropdown user should select quantity according to that the price should be changed How to achieve that?
Heard that we can do it using onChange() function in javascript.Help me to achieve this

```
<p id="price"> <h3> MRP - <?php echo $row['price'] ?> </h3> </p>
<p> Total Price: Total price should load here </p>


    <select class="form-control" name='item' id='item' onchange=''>
    <option>Select Quantity</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Where is your current attempt?  Or are you expecting us to write the whole thing for you?

Comment: @Pete actually I'm new to javascript so I have no idea can you please guide me to do it?

Comment: Looks like you are also new to html - you shouldn't have a `h3` in a `p`, it's not vaild and headnig tags shouldn't be used for styling, just headings.  Google is very good for looking for things like this, a quick search brought [back this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315319/get-value-of-selected-drop-down-list-item) on how to use a select value onchange [and this](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) for changing an element's contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check here the demo 
[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0hqbasw1/)

```
function getamount(value)
 {
 var price=$("#price").html().replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
 var amount=parseInt(value)*parseInt(price);
 alert(amount);
 $("#amount").html("Total Price: " +amount);
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting the value from database and showing the MRP when I tried ur code its showing NaN

Comment: show me the value which come in that div and you can give the id to h3 or not

Comment: make a fiddle with that value as a static for me then i will check what is the problem thanks if you can do this it is easy fro me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the price in php do:

```
<form method="post">
  <select class="form-control" name='item' id='item' onchange=''>
  <option>Select Quantity</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
<?php 
$_POST['item']; //gives you the value that is selected when form is submitted 
?>
```

There is a second way you can get the value onChange then you get the value with javascript. But that is only necessary if you want to directly do something if the user changes the value. Then if you want to do something directly with php with the value you need to do a ajax request.